# KinectSensor.KinectSensors.Count does not recognize a connected kinect?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, kinect, nullreferenceexception

I am writing my first Kinect Application with the following user interface.
[image: Kinect User Interface]

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3FlxTPeKu1g) tutorial for more context.

The concept of the application consists only to integrate the camera of the Kinect into the desktop application. I think it might be important to note that I have a Kinect for Xbox One and its corresponding adapter using the Kinect SDK and Toolkit Version 1.8

The code for the button event handling is the following is the following

```
    private void btnStream_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnStream.Text == "Stream")
        {
           
            if (KinectSensor.KinectSensors.Count > 0)
            {
               
                ksensor = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
                KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged += KinectSensors_StatusChanged;
                
            }
            ksensor.Start();
            lblConnectionID.Text = ksensor.DeviceConnectionId;

        }
        else
        {
            if (ksensor != null && ksensor.IsRunning)
            {
                ksensor.Stop();
                this.btnStream.Text = "Stream";
                this.pbStream.Image = null;
            }
        }

    }

    private void KinectSensors_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.lblStatus.Text = ksensor.Status.ToString(); 
    }
```

and I get the following error from Visual Studio

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The error is pointing to this line of code:

```
ksensor.Start();
```

It is guaranteed that the ksensor variable is declared as follows:

```
private KinectSensor ksensor;
```

My question is why is my variable `KinectSensor.KinectSensors.Count` probably 0 while I am supposed to have 1 as the return value? Does my application not recognize my kinnect?

Comment: @GrantWinney Does that mean that my Kinnect is not connected or what. The counter is supposed to be 1 not 0, right?

Comment: @user1680944 - Grant is correct - can you please edit the question to focus on the `KinectSensor.KinectSensors` count issue?

Comment: @user1680944 - You should change the title and remove the emphasis on the null exception otherwise someone else will mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: @Enigmativity I just did. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it might be important to note that I have a Kinect for Xbox One and its corresponding adapter using the Kinect SDK and Toolkit Version 1.8

The problem is that Microsoft Kinect SDK 1.8 is not compliant with Kinect for Xbox One (see [this link](https://www.dreamspark.com/rss/news.aspx?ID=35&FeedType=productfeed)).

You should install Kinect SDK 2.0 instead (download is available at [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561)). Or if you want to follow that tutorial with Kinect SDK 1.8, you should buy an old [Kinect for Xbox 360](http://compass.xbox.com/assets/89/91/8991d7b5-c14f-4b30-9b89-deb3ba52069c.jpg?n=Xbox360_Sensor_960x450.jpg).

Comment: I thought that the functions implemented in the Kinect SDK 2.0 are the same as the Kinect SDK 1.8 plus the new ones that support the hardware improvement for the Kinect of the XBOX ONE, but I figured out that it is not the case is that right?

Comment: Right. SDK 1.x and SDK 2.0 are quite different actually.